# Real time blur effect for Navigation Bar iOS 7

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

How to achieve the real time blurring effect for the navigation bar in iOS 7.

If i scroll the contents should get blurred behind the navigation bar. Please help me with some code for iOS 7.

Thanks!

I want to achieve like this--

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0qSYN2gw-4-MGhneFF2VnlBVk0/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score -1):

In iOS 7 this effect in navigationBar is achieved easily by setting translucent property to YES:

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = YES;
```